# I'm rendering a react class Some elements seem to have a problem with closing tags but i made sure there's no unclosed tags in between what can i do?

Tags: reactjs

I'm rendering a react class and i'm butting the HTML in the render function but Some elements seem to have a problem with closing tags as it reports that there is some unclosed tags  but i made sure that there's no unclosed tags in between still the problem continues.

i also made sure that the imports are correct and that the render method returns only one element includes all the other elements. How can I solve this?

```
<div>

<h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 30px;"><b> Order </b></h1>
<div class="form-group" style="margin-left:25%; margin-right:25%;">
    <img  style="width: 100%; " />
</div>



<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 100px;"></h1>
    <form action="/submitOrder" method="POST" onSubmit = {validate()}>

  <input type="hidden" name="order[product][name]" />
  <input type="hidden" name="order[product][version]"  />


  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="bd-example">

        <br />

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" /> 


     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />






     <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:23%; margin-right:23%;">
        <div class="bootstrap-iso">
            <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0px; margin-bottom:15px; ">
             <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                 <label class="control-label " for="date">
                  Date
                 </label>
                 <div class="input-group" >
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                   <i class="fa fa-calendar">
                   </i>
                  </div>
                  <input class="form-control" id="date" name="order[orderStartdate]" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text"/>
                 </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
           </div>

           <label class="font-weight-bold" for="Duration">Duration </label>
           <input type="text" id="Duration" class="form-control col-md-12" />
     </div>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />

     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>


</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>




            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">Plugin name</th>
                  <th scope="col">Camera resolution</th>
                  <th scope="col">Number of streams</th>
                  <th scope="col">CPU cores</th>
                  <th scope="col">Memory (GB)</th>
                  <th scope="col">GPU model</th>
                  <th scope="col">GPU utilization</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

                <input type="hidden" name="order[product][plugin][][name]"  /> 
                <input type="hidden" name="order[product][plugin][][pluginVersion]"  />


                <tr>
                  <th scope="row"></th>
                  <td></td>
                  <td>720p</td>
                  <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pluginStreams" placeholder="0" /></td>                      
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="pluginCPU" readonly /></td>
                  <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pluginMemory" readonly /></td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="gpuModel" readonly /></td>
                  <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gpuUtilization" readonly /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <th scope="row"></th>
                  <td>Total hardware</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalPluginStreams"  /></td>                      
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalPluginCPU"    /></td>
                  <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalPluginMemory"  /></td>
                  <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalGPUUtilization" /></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>          
            </div>
        </div>


<div class="container-fluid">

  <h1><b>Deployment Requirements</b></h1>
  <p> <h2><b>Note: Final hardware cost will include also the following items </b></h2>

      <ol type="1">
   <b> <li>ATUN master machine</li></b>
   <b> <li>Additional hardware cost per each slave machine for operating system and ATUN management</li> </b>
   <b><li>The calculations below assume 16 virtual cores slave machines. Other types will be suported later</li></b>
      </ol>
  </p>

    <div class="form-row">       
    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="MachineType">Machine type</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Master" name="masterMachine"  value="Master" readonly />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Slave" name="slaveMachine" value="Slave" readonly />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="Model">Model</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Master" name="masterMachine"  value="8 cores" readonly />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Slave" name="slaveMachine"  value="16 cores" readonly /> 

        <select id="mySelect" class="form-control">
            <option value="16">16 cores</option>
            <option value="32">32 cores</option>
            <option value="40">40 cores</option>

          </select>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="MachineCount">Machine count</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MasterCount" name="order[masterMachine][count]"  value="1" readonly />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalSlaveMachines" name="order[slaveMachine][count]" value="1"   readonly />
   </div>


    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="numberOfCPUs">Virtual CPU cores</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mastertotalCoresUsed" name="order[masterMachine][TotalCores]"  value="8" readonly />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalCoresUsed" name="order[slaveMachine][TotalCores]"   readonly />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalCoresUsed" value="12" name="data[items][0][name]" /> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="numberOfCPUs">Memory (GB)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="masterTotalMemoryUsed" name="order[masterMachine][TotalMemory]"  value="16" readonly />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="totalMemoryUsed" name="order[slaveMachine][TotalMemory]"  readonly />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="numberOfGPUs">Average # GPU</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="masterTotalGPU" name="order[masterMachine][TotalGPU]"  value="0" readonly />
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="slaveTotalGPU" name="order[slaveMachine][TotalGPU]"  readonly />

    </div>

  </div>



    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit order</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a href="/products"> <button class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left" style="margin-right: 5px;"></i>Back</button> </a>

      </form>
</div>




        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this, your jsx had some issues:

```
var NewComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
         <div>
            <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '10px', marginBottom: '30px'}}><b> Order </b></h1>
            <div className="form-group" style={{marginLeft: '25%', marginRight: '25%'}}>
              <img style={{width: '100%'}} />
            </div>
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <h1 style={{textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '100px'}} />
              <form action="/submitOrder" method="POST" onsubmit="{validate()}">
                <input type="hidden" name="order[product][name]" />
                <input type="hidden" name="order[product][version]" />
                <div className="container-fluid">
                  <div className="bd-example">
                    <br />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" /> 
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
                    <div className="form-group" style={{marginLeft: '23%', marginRight: '23%'}}>
                      <div className="bootstrap-iso">
                        <div className="container-fluid" style={{padding: '0px', marginBottom: '15px'}}>
                          <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <label className="control-label " htmlFor="date">
                                Date
                              </label>
                              <div className="input-group">
                                <div className="input-group-addon">
                                  <i className="fa fa-calendar">
                                  </i>
                                </div>
                                <input className="form-control" id="date" name="order[orderStartdate]" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" type="text" />
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <label className="font-weight-bold" htmlFor="Duration">Duration </label>
                      <input type="text" id="Duration" className="form-control col-md-12" />
                    </div>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
                  </div>
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://formden.com/static/cdn/bootstrap-iso.css" />
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
                  <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Plugin name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Camera resolution</th>
                        <th scope="col">Number of streams</th>
                        <th scope="col">CPU cores</th>
                        <th scope="col">Memory (GB)</th>
                        <th scope="col">GPU model</th>
                        <th scope="col">GPU utilization</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <input type="hidden" name="order[product][plugin][][name]" /> 
                      <input type="hidden" name="order[product][plugin][][pluginVersion]" />
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row" />
                        <td />
                        <td>720p</td>
                        <td> <input type="text" className="form-control" id="pluginStreams" placeholder={0} /></td>                      
                        <td><input type="text" className="form-control" id="pluginCPU" readOnly /></td>
                        <td> <input type="text" className="form-control" id="pluginMemory" readOnly /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" className="form-control" id="gpuModel" readOnly /></td>
                        <td> <input type="text" className="form-control" id="gpuUtilization" readOnly /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="row" />
                        <td>Total hardware</td>
                        <td />
                        <td> <input type="text" className="form-control" id="totalPluginStreams" /></td>                      
                        <td><input type="text" className="form-control" id="totalPluginCPU" /></td>
                        <td> <input type="text" className="form-control" id="totalPluginMemory" /></td>
                        <td> <input type="text" className="form-control" id="totalGPUUtilization" /></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>          
                </div>
              </form></div>
            <div className="container-fluid">
              <h1><b>Deployment Requirements</b></h1>
              <p> </p><h2><b>Note: Final hardware cost will include also the following items </b></h2>
              <ol type={1}>
                <b> <li>ATUN master machine</li></b>
                <b> <li>Additional hardware cost per each slave machine for operating system and ATUN management</li> </b>
                <b><li>The calculations below assume 16 virtual cores slave machines. Other types will be suported later</li></b>
              </ol>
              <p />
              <div className="form-row">       
                <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                  <label htmlFor="MachineType">Machine type</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="Master" name="masterMachine" defaultValue="Master" readOnly />
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="Slave" name="slaveMachine" defaultValue="Slave" readOnly />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                  <label htmlFor="Model">Model</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="Master" name="masterMachine" defaultValue="8 cores" readOnly />
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="Slave" name="slaveMachine" defaultValue="16 cores" readOnly /> 
                  <select id="mySelect" className="form-control">
                    <option value={16}>16 cores</option>
                    <option value={32}>32 cores</option>
                    <option value={40}>40 cores</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                  <label htmlFor="MachineCount">Machine count</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="MasterCount" name="order[masterMachine][count]" defaultValue={1} readOnly />
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="totalSlaveMachines" name="order[slaveMachine][count]" defaultValue={1} readOnly />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                  <label htmlFor="numberOfCPUs">Virtual CPU cores</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="mastertotalCoresUsed" name="order[masterMachine][TotalCores]" defaultValue={8} readOnly />
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="totalCoresUsed" name="order[slaveMachine][TotalCores]" readOnly />
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="totalCoresUsed" defaultValue={12} name="data[items][0][name]" /> 
                </div>
                <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                  <label htmlFor="numberOfCPUs">Memory (GB)</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="masterTotalMemoryUsed" name="order[masterMachine][TotalMemory]" defaultValue={16} readOnly />
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="totalMemoryUsed" name="order[slaveMachine][TotalMemory]" readOnly />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                  <label htmlFor="numberOfGPUs">Average # GPU</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="masterTotalGPU" name="order[masterMachine][TotalGPU]" defaultValue={0} readOnly />
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" id="slaveTotalGPU" name="order[slaveMachine][TotalGPU]" readOnly />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form-row">
                <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit order</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a href="/products"> <button className="btn btn-primary"> <i className="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left" style={{marginRight: '5px'}} />Back</button> </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked but can i know exactly where was the error to avoid doing the same mistake in the future

Comment: The input tag needs an closing div for JSX which was missing. 

For future reference, use this platform to convert your raw html to jsx, its very productive tool and will help you build and convert faster.

[https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm]

Answer (score 0):

You have closed a `div`, parent of `form`, before it closes. Check your code, collapse things to help you see more clearly.